# Why can't I connect to this docker compose service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have this docker compose file

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  nginx:
    image: pottava/proxy
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
        - PROXY_URL=http://transmission-container:5080/
        - BASIC_AUTH_USER=admin
        - BASIC_AUTH_PASS=admin
        - ACCESS_LOG=true
  transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission
    container_name: transmission-container
    ports:
      - 5080:9091
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I'm new to docker compose and trying it out for the first time. I need to be able to access the transmission service via `http://localhost:8080` but nginx is returning a 502.

1. How should I change my compose file so that `http://localhost:8080` will connect to the transmission service?
2. How can I make the transmission service not accessible via `http://localhost:5080` and only accessible via `http://localhost:8080` using docker compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the code below, it is working

```yaml
version: "2.1"
services:
  nginx:
    image: pottava/proxy
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
        - PROXY_URL=http://transmission-container:9091/
        - BASIC_AUTH_USER=admin
        - BASIC_AUTH_PASS=admin
        - ACCESS_LOG=true
  transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission
    container_name: transmission-container
    expose:
      - "9091"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

You no need to expose port `5080` to the host, the Nginx container can access directly the container port. The proxy URL needs to point to port `9091`. Now you can't directly access the transmission service but need to go though the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the other container using the service name and container port:

```
 - PROXY_URL=http://transmission:9091/
```

If you do not want to access the transmission service from locahost, do not declare the host port:

```
   ports:
      - 9091
```